# matplotlib, plot through a loop resulting in connected points

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is probably a question that someone has already asked, but I did not found any hint so far and it should be quite simple.

normally I plot from an array like the following:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.plot(arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
```

however I want to do it in a loop and get a similar result, and what I tried so far was:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    ax.plot(arr[i,0], arr[i,1])
```

but it only plotted the last point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're generating the plot using always the same axis (`ax` in your code). In order to print different plots as subplots, you need to use different axes. You can use `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots` to initialize your figure and your list of axes, then you can cycle over the axes with the for loop:

```
fix, axes = plt.subplots(arr.shape[0], figsize=[5,5])
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    ax[i].plot(arr[i,0], arr[i,1])
```

Does it solve your problem?